# Child component still displays even though parent has height of zero

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

```
<div style={{height: "0px"}}>
  <Child />
</div>
```

So basically, the setup above describes my situation. The problem is, `<Child />` is still displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the overflow property of the parent to hidden.

```
<div style={{overflow: hidden; height: "0px"}}>
```